# Spring LDAP Get a user's Full Distinguished Name using Username

Tags: spring, active-directory, ldap

In our AD, we have the following structure for a user's full dn

Cn=username,ou=ou1,ou=ou2,ou=ou3, dc=...

Question is, is it possible to get a user's full dn when we only have the username and ou=ou2...dc... (Missing ou1 value)?

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just run an LDAP search with a query like `(&(CN=username)(objectClass=user))`. Just remember that in general `CN` is a full name, not a username, so if you actually have a username instead of full name you might get better result with `(&(sAMAccountName=username)(objectClass=user))`.